# Error creating dataflow pipeline using custom template on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating dataflow pipeline for Custom Apache Beam Template from GCP console for custom template I already uploaded to Google Cloud Storage.

### 1 After selecting template path, I am seeing this warning or may be error

```
Template metadata error details
Fail to process as Flex Template and Legacy Template. Flex Template Process result:No SDK language information is provided., Legacy Template Process result:(35197769719996987970000d1381234f): Unable to open template file: gs://abc/extraction/templates/cron-template_metadata.
```

I do have `gs://abc/extraction/templates/cron-template` because that's what i specified in my args `--templateLocation=gs://abc/extraction/templates/cron-template` file but not `gs://abc/extraction/templates/cron-template_metadata`.

I am confused if it is a warning or error.

### 2 After I hit button for creating the pipeline

I am getting this error

```
Job creation failed
User cannot act as Dataflow worker service account

Request ID: 38414979878078088000807058
```

What permission do I need in order to create a pipeline.
I have `Dataflow Admin` permission.

Answer (score 1):

### 1 Template metadata error details

```
Fail to process as Flex Template and Legacy Template. Flex Template Process result:No SDK language information is provided., Legacy Template Process result:(35197769719996987970000d1381234f): Unable to open template file: gs://abc/extraction/templates/cron-template_metadata.
```

This is an warning and can be ignored.

### 2 User cannot act as Dataflow worker service account

We need to add a below permission to user who is creating the dataflow pipeline and this can be fixed

`Service Account User`

> Users granted the Service Account User role on a service account can
> use it to indirectly access all the resources to which the service
> account has access. For example, if a service account has been granted
> the Compute Admin role (roles/compute.admin), a user that has been
> granted the Service Account Users role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser)
> on that service account can act as the service account to start a
> Compute Engine instance. In this flow, the user impersonates the
> service account to perform any tasks using its granted roles and
> permissions.

Reference : https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions#user-role

Answer (score 0):

More about the permissions for Flex Templates: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/configuring-flex-templates#permissions